# Save File to Webserver from POST Request

Tags: javascript, php, python, html, http-post

I am making a post request with some javascript to a python script in my `/var/www/cgi-bin` on my web server, and then in this python script I want to save the image file to my html folder, so it can later be retrieved.

Located at `/var/www/html`, but right now the only way I know how to do this is to set the python script to chmod `777` which I do not want to do.

So how else can I save a file that I grab from my webpage using javascript and then send to server with javascript via POST?

Currently when I do this I get an error saying the python does not have permission to save, as its chmod is `755`.

I here is python code, I know it works as the error just says I dont have permission to write the file

```
fh = open("/var/www/html/logo.png", "wb")
fh.write(photo.decode('base64'))
fh.close()
```

Comment: Hmm...put that file into `/tmp` like `fh = open("/tmp/logo.png", "wb")`?

Comment: @KevinGuan what do you mean?

Comment: So you're trying to save a file, and then use JavaScript to send it, but don't have enough permission to write the file?

Comment: @KevinGuan yes that is correct

Comment: Then as I said, I think you could put the file into `/tmp` if you don't need use the file after you sent it. Because the permission of that directory is `777`.

Comment: @KevinGuan I need to use the file after I send it, I need to be able to retrieve it later

Comment: However `/tmp` allows you use the file if you didn't shutdown the server...if you don't save the file into `/tmp` then you need put it in other place where you have the permission to write, like your home directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97106/discussion-between-iqueqiorio-and-kevin-guan).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't want to change the permission of that directory to `777`, you can change the owner of the directory to your HTTP server user, then the user of your web app will be able to write file into that directory because they have `rwx - 7`  permission of the  directory.

To do that, via (since you're using Apache as your web server, remember login as `root):

```
chown -R apache:apache /var/www/cgi-bin/
```

Remember that then only user `apache` and `root` has `rwx` to that directory, and others has `rx`.

And this command means:

```
chown - change the owner of the directory
-R    - operate on files and directories recursively

apache:apache - apache user, apache group
/var/www/cgi-bin/ - the directory
```

Try `man chown` command to check the manual page of `chown` and learn more, [here's a online version](http://www.techonthenet.com/linux/commands/chown.php).

---

If you need change it back, I think the default user of that directory is `root`. So login as `root`, and run command:

```
chown -R root:root /var/www/cgi-bin/
```

---

> We were solved the problem [in chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/97106).

Answer (score 0):

The error message is directly indicating the role/use the python server is running on doesn't have write access to the folder. You need to assign either the role or the web server user. Make sure to give only write access and not write + execute access.

Comment: could you provide more information about how to do that, and the difference between the two options

Comment: What's the web server you are using?

Comment: It is runnign linux if that is what you mean

Comment: how can I change the user?

Comment: Don't change the user. Assign write access to only the webserver user using chmod command. And only to that folder

Comment: I am not sure how to do that? can you provide how to do that?